# Delayed reply with complex type

Tags: c++, qt, dbus

My service is providing a DBus method that returns data with the signature `a(susbs)`. To get this working I have created a data structure (`MyStructure`), implemented stream operators for marshalling/demarshalling and registered the type. As described [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdbusargument.html#details).

So far, so good.

But, since it takes time to generate the response data, I want to send a delayed reply.
So I follow the [manual](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdbusdeclaringslots.html#delayed-replies).
In the example in the manual looks like this:

```cpp
struct RequestData
{
    QString request;
    QString processedData;
    QDBusMessage reply;
};

void sendReply(RequestData *data)
{
    // data->processedData has been initialized with the request's reply
    QDBusMessage &reply = data->reply;

    // send the reply over D-Bus:
    reply << data->processedData; // <-- Here data is added to the reply
    QDBusConnection::sessionBus().send(reply);

    // dispose of the transaction data
    delete data;
}
```

In my case the data I want to add to the reply is of type `QList<MyStructure>`. How do I add that to the reply?

I almost got it working by converting my data to a list of `QVariant`. Like this:

```cpp
void sendReply(RequestData *data, const QList<MyStructure>& result)
{
  QList<QVariant> variantList;
  for (const auto &item : result) {
    QVariant variant;
    variant.setValue(item);
    variantList.append(variant);
  }

  QDBusMessage &reply = data->reply;
  reply << variantList;
  QDBusConnection::sessionBus().send(reply);
}
```

But then the DBus response had the signature `av` where each item in the array was of type `susbs`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this. It was easier than I thought:

```cpp
void sendReply(RequestData *data, const QList<MyStructure>& result)
{
  QVariant v;
  v.setValue(result);

  QDBusMessage &reply = data->reply;
  reply << v;
  QDBusConnection::sessionBus().send(reply);
}
```